# How to increment by month in an SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

This question is a followup question to this one:

[Can I set variables in an SSIS for loop based on a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375378/can-i-set-variables-in-an-ssis-for-loop-based-on-a-query)

The gist of it is that I have a foreach loop container that populates a query with two values as shown below:

```
WHERE SomeDate BETWEEN '1-Jan-2016' AND '31-Dec-2016'
      AND Param1 = ? AND Param2 = ?;
```

However, I've decided to not do a full year pull and decided to do a monthly pull so I changed the query from that to this:

```
WHERE SomeDate BETWEEN '1-Jan-2016' AND '31-Jan-2016'
      AND Param1 = ? AND Param2 = ?;
```

However, I would rather not write 12 separate ones and feel like I can do this in a foreach loop container. The problem is that I have no idea how to increment `SomeDate` by month. `SomeDate` is of type `datetime`.

I know that I would have to nest the month foreach loop container in the first foreach loop container, but am just at a loss at how to set it up such that `Param1` and `Param2` would know what their values are from the first foreach loop container.

Comment: Why would you not take the whole year? SSIS will anyway work with a batch size in the dataflow. Does it take so long to run your query with the whole year? I don't see any performance improvement by doing 12 queries one by one.

Comment: When the resulting CSV is over 100 GB large for a full year, I think monthly would be a better idea.

Comment: But you can still get the whole year from the database and divide it into 12 different CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, if your objective is to create 1 csv file per month, I don't think you need to modify your query. What I think you need, is to use the conditional Split inside the dataflow.

So, you would first create a data source task with your annual query, and then add a conditional split inside:

[image]

And then you would add a Destination File by month:

[image]

Just as a comment, I wouldn't use "CSV" per se. I would use "PSV" where P stands for Pipe Delimited "|". They are usually a lot less trouble to hande in any ETL process.

The greater advantage of this method is that you are not iterating over data and should make it more performant.

Comment: Circled back to this and I appreciate the answer. However, I was trying to have to avoid creating 12 separate items in SSIS. Is there a way to avoid that or is the method you described above the only "real way"?

Comment: No, you can create the files one by one with a loop, but it is less performant.

Comment: Interesting method, I can't say I've seen anything like this. I've accepted your answer as best, thanks for the idea and help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using loops in SQL, you are doing something wrong. Given that, you can use datepart for selecting month in a loop like so:

```
WHERE datepart(mm, SomeDate) = 1
and year(SomeDate) = 2016
AND Param1 = ?
AND Param2 = ?;
```